# Add multiple views in ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am working on an Android App. I have some problem..

Here is my app :
[image]

The pink rectangle is a ScrollView. I want to add TextView to the same ScrollView. I know I need a LinearLayout and add my Views inside this layout. After I need to add the LinearLayout to my ScrollView. Here is my ScrollView class with my methods `setClassicLabel` to implement `TextView`and `setClassicButton` to implement `Button` in my ScrollView.

Here is my `ScrollView.java` :

```
public  class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

private JSONParser  jParser;
private JSONObject  contenuScrollView;
private Context     context;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public MyScrollView(Context context, JSONArray listScrollView) throws JSONException {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws JSONException {
}

/* Création de TextView */
public void setClassicLabel(JSONArray listLabel, LinearLayout ll) throws JSONException {
        if (listLabel.length() > 0)
            {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            for (int i = 0; i < listLabel.length(); i++) {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")),
                                                                                (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));
                params.leftMargin = (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
                params.topMargin = (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y"));
                TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setText(listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
                tv.setTextSize(listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getInt("police_size"));
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("colortext")));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("color")));
                ll.addView(tv, params);
            }
            this.addView(ll, paramsll);
        }
    }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setClassicButton(JSONArray listButton, LinearLayout ll) throws JSONException {
    if (listButton.length() > 0)
    {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < listButton.length(); i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * listButton.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")), 
                (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * listButton.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));

        params.leftMargin = (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * listButton.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
        params.topMargin = (int) (getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * listButton.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y"));

        int dest = listButton.getJSONObject(i).getInt("dest");
        MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context, dest);

        RoundRectShape rect = new RoundRectShape(
                  new float[] {50,50, 50,50, 50,50, 50,50},
                  null,
                  null);
                ShapeDrawable bg = new ShapeDrawable(rect);
                bg.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(listButton.getJSONObject(i).getString("color")));

        myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
        myButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(listButton.getJSONObject(i).getString("colortext")));
        //BitmapDrawable bdra = new BitmapDrawable(downloadBitmap(listButton.getJSONObject(i).getString("http")));
        myButton.setText(listButton.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
        myButton.getBackground().setAlpha(30);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyButton button = (MyButton)view;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClassicView.class);
                Content content = new Content(button.getDestination());
                intent.putExtra("CONTENT", content);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ll.addView(myButton, params);
    }
    this.addView(ll, paramsll);
}
}
}
```

`MyScrollView` heritates from ScrollView. The problem is the next :

When I create my ScrollView with the method `setClassicScrollView`, i call my methods `setClassicLabel` and `setClassicButton` to implements theses two views in my ScrollView. But i can only set Button or Label. I can't set one label and one button. I must have a problem who comes from a layout.. I am on it for two days

Here is my method `setClassicScrollView` :

```
public void setClassicScrollView(JSONArray listScrollView, RelativeLayout rl) throws JSONException {
        if (listScrollView.length() > 0) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            for (int i = 0; i  < listScrollView.length(); i++) {
                MyScrollView myScrollView = new MyScrollView(this, listScrollView);
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels * listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));
                params.leftMargin = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
                params.topMargin = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y"));
                myScrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                myScrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
                myScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                myScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount();
                myScrollView.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

                //myScrollView.setClassicLabel(listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Label"), ll);
                myScrollView.setClassicButton(listScrollView.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("Button"), ll);

                rl.addView(myScrollView);
            }
        }
    }
```

Someone has an idea of how I can set TextViews and Buttons in the same ScrollView ?

Comment: How about using a ListView instead?

Comment: Why not just doing that in the layout itself ? And then code accordingly. It will so easy to do that way and it's not that you can't customize it after.

Comment: I can't use a ListView. I just want set TextView and Buttons in the same ScrollView.

Comment: @mike20132013 Which layout ? When i try to set two objects, i got an error : ScrollView can host only one child

Comment: Obviously.. Scroll view can hold only one child view..Look at my answer.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, you speak about which layout ?

Comment: Put all buttons and stuff in a ViewGroup, and put that ViewGroup as a child of ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the layout for your scroll view.**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spending_report_cycle_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SomeView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#008080"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content_1"
            android:name="com.mike.passintents.Fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SomeView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#008080"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/spending_report_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#333333" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here.. In the scroll view, I have one linear layout as one child and after that I have other views inside the linear layout.

Comment: I have no xml. I all created programmatically

Comment: I am just suggesting that instead of doing everything programmatically , why not just make in the layout like above.

Comment: What are exactly trying to do in your app ?

Comment: I set my Views in my Activity with a json file. I have a json file which with I instantiate my Views.